# TIBCO MDM 9 : log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (RulebaseCustomFunction)

Tags: log4j, tibco, master-data-management, tibco-mdm

Getting below error while I am trying to print `MqLog` to **elink.log** via `RulebaseCustomFunction` (MDM 9)\

```
ERROR [stderr] (TIBCO EMS Session Dispatcher (895)) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (RulebaseCustomFunction).
ERROR [stderr] (TIBCO EMS Session Dispatcher (895)) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

How to Configure in order to avoid above error?

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default `log4j` configuration provided out-of-box does not have appender defined for `RulebaseCustomFunction`.  However, you can always add new appender to `ConfigValues.xml`
Try adding below in "Logging" category-

```xml
<ConfValue description="The debugging logging level CustomRulebaseFunction" name="Logging Level for CustomRulebaseFunction" propname="log4j.logger.RulebaseCustomFunction" sinceVersion="8.0" visibility="All" isHotDeployable="true" isHidden="false">
  <ConfString default="DEBUG,elink,error" value="DEBUG,elink,error"/>
</ConfValue>
```